# IIS 7.0 - Default Web Site is not working

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7, webserver

Just now I added IIS in my system. And I try to start Default Web Site in IIS. But it will throwing following error,

```
    The format of the specified network name is invalid (Exception from HRESULT:0x800704BE)
```

Here my Screen-shot,

[image]

So, I don't know what i did..? Then I fail to see how can I solve this problem.

How should I solve this exception?

Comment: check the bindings, the pool, the directory, the permissions of directory...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be because the IP 127.0.0.1 - localhost may not listen by computer

Check with below command in command prompt:

```
netsh http show iplisten
```

It should return the `127.0.0.1`.

If it is not there then add it to using below command:

```
netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1
```

If the IP address is successfully added, you receive the following message: 
IP address successfully added.

Comment: Thnks for your response. I want to another one help. Actually, Am added my application to IIS Server. And am start that Application. But it will showing Unable to Connect. I don't know about any configuration missing. So, please suggest something..

Comment: It is difficult to answer with this information. Can you please provide more information like how the application is created? Exact error message?

Comment: Am, Normally I added to new site and I given to physical path of my Application directory. Then I set default port number(80).

Comment: Try to give some other port like 9999 and try to start the application

Comment: yea, I changed port number also. But it will same response. If you free means, Please see my configuration through Team Viewer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163789/discussion-between-sathish-anish-and-mittal).

Comment: Sorry, I can not spend the time to check all the configuration. However, the error message stated by you "Unable to connect" is very rare, I have googled it but didn't find anything on that. It would be appreciated if you can share the whole error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to solve this issue:

#### 1. Get currently listed IP:

`netsh http show iplisten`
(this will list just one IP of your machine)

#### 2. Delete old IP with this command:

`netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=11.22.33.44`

(where 11.22.33.44 is the IP received from #1)

#### 3. Next, set the service UP to listen to all the IPs:

`netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0`

(if you dont want to open for all IPs then just pass single IP)

#### 4. To make these changes reflected, Restart IIS using:

`iisreset`